# SQL Warning INSERT INTO %%bmk%%

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan

I have warning on my execution plan:

```
insert [#TABLE] select *, %%bmk%% from [#TABLE]

<Warnings>
     <MemoryGrantWarning GrantWarningKind="Excessive Grant" RequestedMemory="16616" GrantedMemory="16616" MaxUsedMemory="408" />
</Warnings>
```

what should i watch to remove this warning?

Comment: Upload the XML of the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkCTAaIWv

Comment: This corresponds to the creation of an index NC with include to column NVarchar(MAX). i think the problem is NVarchar(MAX)

Comment: Yes it may be the actual nvarchar(MAX) column lengths are much smaller than the guestimate. It seems the temp table doesn't have a clustered index. If the non-clustered index is the only one on the temp table, consider changing it to clustered and remove the included column.

Comment: it's ok Thanks a lot